# How to check if a record exist in sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview

Hi in Application i have already inserted some data into my `sqlite` database now i want to check the particular record is already inserted or not in  `sqlite`. I'm working in `UITableView`. I want to check using my product id it is a unique id. Id  which comes from my server. I want check the particular id is exit in my `sqlite` database. I have stored my id in `NSMutableArray`.

My code to store the arrayid into a string in my `UITableViewcell`.

```
 for (int i=0; i<[menuarray2 count]; i++) {
    rowvalue =[menuarray2 objectAtIndex:i];
     NSLog(@"rowid%@",rowvalue);
}
```

I have passed the string to my sqlite query its showing null.

```
   -(void)checkdata:(NSString*)query{
      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sqlite"];

  if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&_myDataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
       NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",query];

       char *errmsg=nil;

    if(sqlite3_exec(_myDataBase, [querySQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg)==SQLITE_OK)
      {
        NSLog(@".. id ..");
      }
    }
    sqlite3_close(_myDataBase);
  }
```

-(void)rowcount{

```
 NSLog(@"rowdata%@",rowvalue);
   NSString  *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from br where PID='%@'",rowvalue];
  NSLog(@"%@",sql);
[self checkdata:sql];
}
```

I'm using above to check but its showing null in console which print the query like

```
SELECT * from br where PID='(null)'
```

Please tell me how to resolve this issue i have stuck here for long time please help me out.

Thanks..

Comment: u want to check ur sqlite in manually or progrmaticlly

Comment: Try changing the sql statement from `SELECT * from br where PID='(null)'` to `SELECT * from br where PID like '%null%'`

Comment: try this SELECT * from br where PID LIKE '%null%' this method is used for check or match the particular object in your table

Comment: that s y before u need to check, it is null or not, if it is null show the insert method else delete part